# How to fix 'Uncaught TypeError: number is not a function error' and 'Failed to load resource' error

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why does the code have an error?

```
var images = ['/test/img/Gallery/large/4cba0c8a-4acc-4f4a-9d71-0a444afdf48d.jpg','/test/img/Gallery/large/4cba0ca8-2158-41af-829a-0a444afdf48d.jpg','/test/img/Gallery/large/4cbc549a-5228-433f-b0bc-0a444afdf48d.jpg'];
$('.triggerNext').click(function(){
    nextImage();
    return false;
});
function nextImage(){
    currentImage = $('.Pagepage:eq(0)').val();
    nextImage = parseInt(currentImage)+1;
    $('#imageCurrent').attr('src',images[nextImage]);
    $('#imageCurrent') .css('position','absolute').css('left',($(window).width()- $('#imageCurrent').width() )/2);
    $('.Pagepage').val(nextImage);
}
```

It runs correctly the first time but gets an error after clicking.

Yet, the code below runs fine without any errors:

```
var images = ['/test/img/Gallery/large/4cba0c8a-4acc-4f4a-9d71-0a444afdf48d.jpg','/test/img/Gallery/large/4cba0ca8-2158-41af-829a-0a444afdf48d.jpg','/test/img/Gallery/large/4cbc549a-5228-433f-b0bc-0a444afdf48d.jpg'];
$('.triggerNext').click(function(){
    currentImage = $('.Pagepage:eq(0)').val();
    nextImage = parseInt(currentImage)+1;
    $('#imageCurrent').attr('src',images[nextImage]);
    $('#imageCurrent') .css('position','absolute').css('left',($(window).width()- $('#imageCurrent').width() )/2);
    $('.Pagepage').val(nextImage);
    return false;
});
```

[image]

Comment: Don't give us the source from your PHP file, give us the source from your HTML page (right click->View source)

Comment: Also, what error messages are you seeing? Find the error console in the browser you are using, and if you are using Firefox then install Firebug

Comment: If i use fisrt code ,it'll change next page. but if i use below code, it run  fine. I want it change image in array "images"

Comment: If there is an error, then there will be a message telling you what the error is. You need to find that error message in your browser and tell *us*. The easiest way to find the error message if you are using Firefox is to install Firebug.

Comment: I can't believe two people marked this as favourite. Not even know what the error message is..

Comment: it change page immediately , it dont run function nextImage() after click 2

Comment: @jAndy: I use favorites as bookmarks to mark questions where I'm interested in how the whole thing turns out, not because they are "good" questions. In this case I marked it because it was a "bad" question :-)

Comment: jAndy - FYI, I marked it as a favourite because I saw it without the ability to look closer at it and wanted to find it again. That's one way I use my favourites list. I am now unmarking it again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like your're overwritting your `function` here:

```
nextImage = parseInt(currentImage)+1;
```

Either change the name from your `function` or `variable`. Even better, don't use a `global namespace`. Anyway, you can't overwrite the `name` from a function, your're overwritting the function itself.

After the above line, `nextImage` contains a `Number` which obviously cannot get executed.

**right from the comments**

> just replace nextImage = parseInt(currentImage)+1; with var nextImage = > parseInt(currentImage)+1; – Alin Purcaru

Using a `var` statement, also avoids the `nextImage` from going into the global namespace.

Comment: Just replace `nextImage = parseInt(currentImage)+1;` with `var nextImage = parseInt(currentImage)+1;`

Comment: @meotimdihia: of course it will, the first time the identifier `nextImage` does contain a function (reference), which then gets overwritten by a number.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
var nextImage = parseInt(currentImage)+1;
```

so you don't overwrite your function name